# Dropdown list using Entity Framework in _layout page

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

Using Razor Pages.  I want a dropdown list in the header which is created in _Layout.cshtml.  This will be populated by a EF database query based on the login user ID.  This list will be a global filter for any of the queries.  It needs to respond to selection change.  It will use cookies to keep track from session to session.  Then each page that displays data will be able to access this value and filter its results.  Each page could just read the cookie value or have some access to the value in the dropdown list.

Tried using partial and view component.  Either way doesn't work because it always tries to pass the Model of the calling page (Index, Create, Report) since it is loaded by each and not exactly by the _Layout which doesn't have a model.  So, now I can't use a model in the Partial or View Component to bind the drop down list.

I also couldn't get the changing of the dropdown list to fire the OnPostAsync event.

This seems like it isn't even possible based on all the attempts I made.  I'm assuming it probably requires javascript to do all of the work but I'm not sure the correct approach to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base class for your controllers, which adds the required data to the ViewBag on every request. Note: The following code is based on ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET Core, but afaik the process is similar.

```
public class ApplicationControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // use ViewResultBase, if you need logic for both full and partial views. Since you want to add info for the _Layout page, ViewResult is better.
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult viewResult)
        {
            // Give the ViewBag item a unique name, that will not be used elsewhere, so you don't overwrite anything by accident.
            // Use the data from ViewBag to populate your dropdown.
            viewResult.ViewBag.DropDownItems = GetDropDownItems(); // implement GetDropDownItems accordingly, preferrably with caching!
        }
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

As for the second part of your question about calling the OnPostAsync when the DropDownList changes its value: Yes, you can use JS for this, unless you want to add an extra form around it with an extra submit button. The form may make sense in any case, but you can use the onchange handler to submit the form immediately, when the dropdown's value changes, instead of requiring manual submission of the form.